# Swift to Kotlin puzzle

Tags: swift, kotlin

I am in the process of converting some iOS code(Swift) to Android(Kotlin) that is used to control a Bluetooth device (BLE).

I believe there are some differences between Swift and Kotlin and Unsigned Ints etc but I can't seem to get the same output.

**iOS code : Outputs 13365**

```
print ("IMPORTANT \(fourthData as NSData)") // Value is 0x3534
var fourth = Int32()
_ = Swift.withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &fourth, { fourthData.copyBytes(to: $0) } )
print ("IMPORTANT \(fourth)") // 13365
```

**Android code : Output is 13620**

```
@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes // just to make it clear that the experimental unsigned types are used
    fun ByteArray.toHexString() = asUByteArray().joinToString("") { it.toString(16).padStart(2, '0') }

Log.i("Decode", fourthData.toHexString()) // 3534 
Log.i("Decode", "${fourthData.toHexString().toUInt(16)}") //13620
```

I have tried Int, UInt BigInteger and Long.  What am I missing

Comment: What's the value of your `fourthData` in the Kotlin example?

Comment: 13620 is the correct decimal value for 0x3534

Comment: 13365  is the correct decimal value for 0x3435 – maybe some typo involved?

Comment: Well, this is obviously a problem of Big Endian vs Little Endian. Kotlin (Java) uses always only Big Endian. Swift uses machine representation, which is usually Little Endian. Can be probably fixed using `Int32(bigEndian: fourth)`. However, converting `Data` to `Int` this way is just strange.

Comment: Really that's super useful will give it a go thank you

Comment: @de. I think you could be right, one of them isn't reversing the ByteArray/NSData properly

Comment: @Sulthan  You were correct, if you would like tp post up the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commenters already pointed out, values `13620` and `13365` are `0x3534` and  `0x3435` respectively. In other words, the values differ by the byte ordering.

Decadic 32-bit number `13620` is equal to `0x00003534` in hexadecimal, therefore it will be represented by four bytes `00-00-35-34`.

However, computers usually don't represent the value in that order. Two commonly used representations are Big Endian and Little Endian. The Big Endian will represent bytes in the natural order `00-00-35-34` but Little Endian will have bytes swapped to `00-00-34-35`.

Java (Kotlin) always uses Big Endian representation for everything. On the other hand, if you just get the memory layout of an `Int` in Swift, you get the machine representation. The machine representation is usually Little Endian but that can differ between architectures. You should always be careful when directly reinterpreting numeric values as bytes or viceversa.

In this specific case, if you are sure the `Data` contains a Big Endian integer, you can use `Int32(bigEndian: fourth)` to swap the values from Big Endian to machine representation.